# Only Wifi is working in bluetooth+wifi combo adapter

Tags: drivers, 22.04, bluetooth, laptop, adapter

My laptop has Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 adapter which is Wifi and Bluetooth combo. 
When I installed Ubuntu 22.04, it did not have either wifi or bluetooth working. I installed a wifi adapter from some solutions online and it worked. But none of the solution is working for the Bluetooth. 
"lsusb" command is not showing any bluetooth on my device. 
Is there any specific driver for Dual band + Bluetooth combo adapters for linux? Cause it works fine with windows.

Comment: Is this a desktop computer?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 comes with Linux kernel 5.15, which hasn't a great Bluetooth dongle support.

1. Update your kernel to a higher version such as **6.5** or above (6.5 worked for me).
2. Install bluetooth dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt install blueman bluez bluez-tools
   ```
3. Enable and start bluetooth service

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
   sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
   ```
4. Install `libspa-0.2-bluetooth` **if headphones or speakers don't work**.

   ```
   sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth
   ```

   This package contains a plugin to make Bluetooth audio devices such as speakers and headsets available to the PipeWire server.
   Probably it will work for your case, since Ubuntu 22.04 uses PipeWire by default.
5. Reboot

Hope it helps.